# mysql full join with big-query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two `big-select-query` that each return  table, such tbl1 and tbl2, and I want to do `full join` them. But, because `mysql` don't support `full join`, I must use`left join - union - right join`, and my query becomes tooooo large!

I used then, TEMPORARY tables such:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl1 ( big-query );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl2 ( big-query );

SELECT ...  FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON  ...
UNION
SELECT ...  FROM tbl1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 ON  ...
```

that accurs error: `Can't reopen table`

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: You problem seems like [`B.5.7.2 TEMPORARY Table Problems`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a good solution. do you know it?

Comment: create a view of your big query?

Comment: My big query is always changing and can not be as a view. Is there no solution?!